# What are the performance implications of casting between simple structs with the same memory?

Tags: rust, struct, casting

I implemented `From` [Point3](https://docs.rs/cgmath/0.18.0/cgmath/struct.Point3.html) for `Vertex` a simple struct with one field called position that is `[f32; 3]`. Point3 is marked as `#[repr(C)]` which I think means that the 3 `f32` will be right next to each other in memory, with no padding for alignment. I also think that `[f32, 3]` will also have no padding for alignment. Is this true? If it is true, does that mean there is a way to "reinterpret" the memory of `Point3` as `Vertex`? If it is not true, what is are the performance implications? I'm sorry if this is not clear, I am asking this question to understand a bit more about the low level parts of Rust.

```
impl From<cgmath::Point3<f32>> for Vertex {
    fn from(vertex: cgmath::Point3<f32>) -> Self {
        Vertex {
            position: [vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z],
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's a little weird for me that this struct is marked as repr C since it's doesn't look like it need to, no repr C guarantee order but not padding, just let compiler do its job of optimizing your code. It's not safe to assume this struct is packed

Comment: [Similar question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70697768/transmute-struct-into-array-in-rust/70699596#70699596). Btw: both `Point3<f32>` and `[f32;3]` are aligned to 4 bytes, because `f32` is. (For `Point3` to be aligned to 1 byte, it would have to be marked `repr(packed)`.) [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4a8b5b8fc75c7a608cb1d72e3983e09c) (The layouts are equal, which means that `mem::transmute` should be allowed, I think. But I personally wouldn't feel certain enough of this to try. The performance is probably equal anyway.)

Comment: Point3 needs to be repr(C) in my case because it is interfacing with the Vulkan API. The API expects the memory to be just so. @Stargateur

Comment: Thank you Caesar! any::type_name and alloc::Layout are just what i needed to satisfy my curiosity.