# Why does std::mem::transmute not work when both types are known to have the exact same memory layout?

Tags: rust, casting, unsafe, const-generics, transmute

Let me preface with saying that I'm actively looking into other options than `transmute`, I was just suprised that `transmute` doesn't compile in this case.

I'm working on a `Builder` derive library, that checks at compile time which fields are initialized. For this purpose I'm using const generics. I got the basics working, but I'm trying to add a feature, and because of that I was looking at `transmute`.

If I'd use `transmute`, an example of a setter would look as follows:

```rust
#[derive(Builder)]
pub struct Foo<const SIZE: usize> {
    bar: [usize; SIZE],
}

// Just the setter part of the macro expansion:
impl<const SIZE: usize> FooBuilder<SIZE, false> {
    pub fn bar(mut self, bar: [usize; SIZE]) -> FooBuilder<SIZE, true> {
        self.data.bar = Some(bar);
        unsafe { std::mem::transmute(self) }
    }
}
```

But transmute doesn't work like this. `SIZE` is exactly the same and the boolean doesn't have any effect on the underlying data, but still I get:

```
cannot transmute between types of different sizes, or dependently-sized types
source type: `test::const_generic::FooBuilder<SIZE, false>` (size can vary because of [usize; SIZE])
target type: `test::const_generic::FooBuilder<SIZE, true>` (size can vary because of [usize; SIZE])
```

I was just curious why this restriction is in place. Can anyone explain this to me?

```rust
// simplified macro expansion:
pub struct Foo<const SIZE: usize> {
    bar: [usize; SIZE],
}

impl <const SIZE: usize> Foo<SIZE> {
    fn builder() -> FooBuilder<SIZE, false> {
        FooBuilder::new()
    }
}

pub struct FooBuilder<const SIZE: usize, const __BUILDER_CONST: bool> {
    bar: Option<[usize; SIZE]>,
}

impl<const SIZE: usize> FooBuilder<SIZE, false> {
    pub fn new() -> FooBuilder<SIZE, false> {
        FooBuilder {
            bar: None,
        }
    }
}

impl<const SIZE: usize> FooBuilder<SIZE, false> {
    pub fn bar(mut self, bar: [usize; SIZE]) -> FooBuilder<SIZE, true> {
        self.bar = Some(bar);
        unsafe { std::mem::transmute(self) } 
              // ^ Should work, because the value of `__BUILDER_CONST` has no influence
              // on the layout of the struct, and `SIZE` is identical
    }
}

impl<const SIZE: usize> FooBuilder<SIZE, true> {
    pub fn build(self) -> Foo<SIZE> {
        Foo::<SIZE> {
            bar: self.bar.unwrap()
        }
    }
}
```

Btw, the actual setter looks more as follows, I was just running into some weird lifetime issues when adding a new feature (using `impl AsRef<T>` as a setter input type)

```rust
impl<const SIZE: usize> FooBuilder<SIZE, false> {
    pub fn bar(self, bar: [usize; SIZE]) -> FooBuilder<SIZE, true> {
        let mut data = self.data;
        data.bar = Some(bar);
        FooBuilder { data }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actual [MRE](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=84a6f37b2c6270e29a8edccbe49d6f04) without errors. Anyway: Rust doesn't guarantee anything about the layout of structs, if I understand correctly not even about `FooBuilder<_, false>` and `FooBuilder<_, true>`. They might not actually have the same size. Transmute not working in this case is probably an arbitrary unnecessary restriction of the implementation of transmute. You could use `transmute_unchecked`. [Note](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70699596/401059) that transmute probably doesn't help performance.

Comment: Ah thanks, I will update the MRE when I'm behind my computer again. The reason I tried `transmute` was not because of performance, but rather because I was getting lifetime issues if I wanted the setter to accept `impl AsRef<str> +'a` (if the field_ty was &'a str). Sadly `transmute_unchecled` isn't [available outside of nightly](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/intrinsics/fn.transmute_unchecked.html) so I'm still looking for a solution.

Comment: How about not using `transmute` or `unsafe` at all? [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7230482ce135a01f3f180dadc01e1e06).

Comment: That is basically what I'm doing currently, see the bottom piece of code. But I'm running into [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d7984e1e4fb630d92a6685693c61c1f6)

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your question more thoroughly and tell you right away: Trying to transmute yourself out of lifetime errors you don't understand is a terrible idea. I'm not entirely certain, but I think this is based on a misunderstanding of lifetimes. I'm not confident enough to explain, but consider that e.g. `String` is `'static`, so you'd be allowed to pass it in, and it'd be dropped at the end of `bar`. You can get around this with `&'a impl AsRef<str>`, I think the ergonomic disadvantage is unavoidable. Anyway, maybe post a separate SO question for the lifetime issue?

Comment: @Caesar or just take `&'a str` and have the caller add `&` or `.as_ref()` I think at that point, that's more straight forward/convenient.

Answer (score 1):

The analysis in the compiler is just too restrictive. It doesn't allow any transmute that depends on dynamic size even when we can prove the sizes are equal.

However, note that in your case the transmute is incorrect: you need to add `#[repr(transparent)]` to the struct.